# .NET resolves a class to the wrong DLL

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

My C# project has references to two third party DLLs. This is important because it means I don't have access to source code and can't modify or recompile these two DLLs.

Let's call them dll A and dll B. Here's what dll A looks like:

```
namespace ThirdParty.Foo
{
  public class Bar
  {
    ...snip...
  }

  public class Something
  {
    public Bar MyProperty { get; set; }
  }
}
```

And here's what dll B looks like:

```
namespace ThirdParty.Foo
{
  public class Bar
  {
    ...snip...
  }

  public class SomethingElse
  {
    public Bar MyProperty { get; set; }
  }
}
```

As you can see, they have the same namespace and they both define a class with the same name. My C# code needs a reference to both DLLs. I use the alias property on the reference to be able to distinguish between the two references and I also `extern alias firstDll` and  `extern alias secondDll` at the top of my C# file. So far so good.

It seems obvious to me that the type of `Something.MyProperty` is firstDll.ThirdParty.Foo.Bar and the type of `SomethingElse.MyProperty` is secondDll.ThirdParty.Foo.Bar but for some reason, Visual Studio gets confused and resolves the type of both properties to the same `Bar` class in firstDll.

Is there a way for me to "force" VisualStudio to resolve the correct type?

EDIT: 
the error I'm getting in Visual Studio is: Cannot implicitly convert type 'ThirdParty.Foo.Bar [d:\MySolution\References\Second.dll]' to 'ThirpParty.Foo.Bar [d:\MySolution\References\First.dll]'

Comment: Just to make sure, you want to distinguish between two types of exactly the same name in exactly the same namespace, but from two different referenced assemblies, correct?

Comment: You could enumerate all the types from each `Assembly` individually and then instantiate the one you want using `Activator.GetInstance()`. However, this probably won't help at design time.

Comment: @JanDoerrenhaus yes that's correct and what's important to realize is that these are 3rd party DLLs, I can't recompile or anything. I am just very surprised that VS.NET is not resolving a type to the 'Bar' in the corresponding DLL.

Comment: Is the compiler getting confused or just the editor?

Comment: Could you please comment on @BenVoigt question ?

Comment: @BenVoigt my solution does not build because of this issue therefore I assume its not just the editor.

Comment: Can you show the line where the compiler is reporting the conversion error?  I'm pretty sure that the SomethingElse class property is referencing the correct type; it's defined in the same assembly, so the metadata token for the property type shouldn't require any assembly binding to resolve it.  Further, type references use the fully-qualified name of the type in the metadata, so as long as your assemblies have different names, there should be no ambiguity.

Comment: @DanBryant Dan, it so happens that my DLLs did indeed have the exact same physical name. To avoid confusion I manually renamed one of them but you make me think that the metadata for the property type probably still references the original file name which would explain why VS.NET is looking at the type in the wrong DLL.

Comment: @desautelsj, if the assembly-qualified name of the type is exactly the same in both cases, you're going to have a lot of problems.  Is it an option at all to recompile one of the third-party assemblies using a tool to replace the root namespace with a different name?

Comment: @DanBryant I contacted the vendor to ask them to change the name of of the DLLs. Hopefully they'll agree. If not, do you know of a tool to replace namespace like you mentioned?

Answer (score 5):

Create a DLL that will serve as a wrapper for DLL A. Let's call the new DLL "C". Your project will then reference DLL B and C.

Answer (score 2):

If the two types have the same name and namespace, then you are pretty much stuck. In C#, the name/identifier is quite important, "best fit" will only work in special situations.

However, you could write wrappers for the two different types, and make those wrappers have different names. By having two different (or even one) project just for the wrapper, you could have only one reference, thus effectively resolving the conflict "by force".

Answer (score 2):

Something that works(for me it did referenced correctly) is the following,first(as you probably already did)click each dll in the references and assign an alias and place the proper extern alias.After to use the class Something and SomethingElse(and properly assign the Bar Property) create one class for each of those classes(Something and SomethingElse)and derive from them and shadow the MyProperty property:

```
public class TestFirst : first.ThirdParty.Foo.Something
{
    //here you shadow and since you must provide the alias
    //and the fully qualified name it will bet set to the
    //right Bar class,same bellow in testsecond.
    public first.ThirdParty.Foo.Bar MyProperty { get; set; }
}

public class TestSecond : second.ThirdParty.Foo.SomethingElse
{
    public second.ThirdParty.Foo.Bar MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

After its just business as usual:

```
TestSecond t = new TestSecond();
t.MyProperty = new second.ThirdParty.Foo.Bar();
```

Comment: I'll try that. However, there are a few dozen classes in this situation so it might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

I would load the dlls explicitly via Assembly.Load then do a createinstance on the types you need then invoke the methods via dynamic - that's because I am lazy. 
The other (not lazy) way is to then use reflection to find the method and invoke it.

Comment: Might work, but circumventing the issue by using Reflection may have serious performance impacts.

Comment: 'Assembly.Load' is a very interesting suggestion, let me look into it.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have an extreme case here where the two assemblies not only have the same namespace, but also the same full assembly name (meaning the types have the same assembly-qualified name), you may want to consider more extreme measures to resolve it.  If it's a fully managed DLL (no native code mixed in) and not strong named (or you're okay with removing the strong naming), you may be able to get away with a procedure like this:

1. Run [ildasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7dy01k1.aspx) and output to a .il file on disk.
2. Modify the .il file using a careful search and replace to change the root namespace for all types (be cautious for inner namespaces or type names that contain the same text as the root namespace.)
3. Run the modified file through [ilasm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx.aspx) to build a new .dll with the changes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the keyword `var` instead of specifying the type explicitly to avoid ambiguous references

```
var x = new ThirdParty.Foo.Something();
var y = new ThirdParty.Foo.SomethingElse();

var barX = x.MyProperty;
var barY = y.MyProperty;
```

Comment: I expect `barY` in your example to be of type 'second.ThirdParty.Foo.Bar' but VS.NET says that it's 'first.ThirParty.Bar'. I don't see how your suggestion will help solve this problem.